# Since New Snapshot of Hard Drive on EC2 I can't Login to Plesk

Tags: amazon-ec2, plesk

Recently on my EC2 Instance I wanted to increase the volume of the drive, so took a snapshot of my previous instance and made a new one with a much bigger volume. I had Plesk installed and used to log in to it by typing in the Elastic IP address and 8443, so

http://52.215.x.x:8443 - and the elastic IP would point to my private DNS IP.

Since the new volume has been in place, I try to log in with my elastic IP address as before but the following comes up:

"This site can’t be reached

ip-172-31-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal took too long to respond."

I don't understand why, but think the new volume might be on a different private IP?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Louk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try steps from "**Changing IP address**" at

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213376929-How-to-deploy-Plesk-on-the-Amazon-EC2-service

Comment: Thank you, this gave me a one time login path for plesk where I found the new path that worked, you have made my day!